# Alfresco Code location for preferred document view renderer

Tags: java, alfresco

I have modified the Alfresco Community 5.0c and somehow have created a bug. When I am in the document library, change the View Mode(top right from Options) to simple view, the documents are displayed OK. When I refresh the page, instead of the simple view, I get the default detailed view.

The problem is, I do not understand where the `Alfresco.DocumentList.options.viewRendererName`(*documentlist.js*) attribute is set. Apparently this is somehow done outside the *documentlist.js* file, but I could not manage to find out where.

Can you please point me in the right direction? I would like to know exactly where the above mentioned attribute is set with the user's preferred view mode(gotten probably from preferences).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In documentlist-v2.get.js, the `documentList` var is the configuration for Documentlist(found indocumentlist.js). I could not find *how* the config values are set in the object - I just assume it's some framework magic.

My problem was in documentlist.lib.js, in the function `doclibCommon()` where I replaced the check `model.preferences.simpleView === true` with `model.preferences.simpleView` - thought it was the same result, with improved readability. Because of this, the if clause was evaluated different than expected.